# Make BeautifulSoup recognize word breaks caused by HTML <li> elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup4 does not recognize that it should would break between `<li>` elements when extracting text:

Demo program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


HTML="""
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li>First Element</li><li>Second element</li>
</ul>
</body>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup( HTML, 'html.parser' )
print(soup.find('body').text.strip())
```

Output:

```
First ElementSecond element
```

Desired output:

```
First Element Second element
```

I guess I could just globally add a space before all `<li>` elements. That seems like a hack?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.stripped_strings` of `soup` to extract the text while preserving the whitespaces between elements

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML = """
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li>First Element</li><li>Second element</li>
</ul>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'html.parser')
print(' '.join(soup.body.stripped_strings))
```

Or extract the text of each `<li>` element separately and then join them

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML="""
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li>First Element</li><li>Second element</li>
</ul>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup( HTML, 'html.parser' )
lis = soup.find_all('li')
text = ' '.join([li.text.strip() for li in lis])
print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if they are going to be `<li>` elements. I'll try the `.stripped_strings.`